# Is that possible to use hadoop only with python?

Tags: python, hadoop

Suppose that it's much more easier for me to use python, because of numpy library,

can i write my whole MapReduce tasks with python, without any java code

Mainly, I need to have alot of MapReduce rounds. Is that related to "Job Chaining?"

What is the right to do such thing?

Comment: I dont have problem to use "Hadoop Streaming", I ask whether if  I can build my whole application with that.

Comment: You might look at Apache Spark.  It works with python, among other things.

Comment: Have you tried to write a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept ? If so, what seems to be the problem? Your question is very vague.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath For example, how can i do Conf.set("name","value") when im not using Java?

Comment: @vefthym can you give me a hint?

Comment: @member555 please, clarify what you need exactly in your question, otherwise it will be probably voted to be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Apache Spark. It is much faster than simple Hadoop MapReduce model. It supports Python, Scala and Java, to write your applications.